# Regex messy addresses with Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I need to extract the address **only** from the following set of strings:

1. `143 Evergreen Forest Court` (this one is fine as is)
2. `326 Hambrick Park Fayetteville, GA 30215`
3. `RE: Owner's Policy - 112 Shagbark Ln Mooresville, NC 28115`
4. `RE: Owner's Policy - 540 Clearbrook Dr Covington, GA 30016`
5. `Closed 9/1/21 4421 Home Stakes Dr Parkton, NC 28371`
6. `RP 9/16- 352 Hampton St Elloree, SC 29047`
7. `RP: 9/15- 124 Lake Grove Rd Simpsonville, SC 29681`
8. `FHA 3/2/22- 6083 Holiday Blvd Forest Park, GA 30297`
9. `RD 10/1/21 Roxanne Sellers- 311 Woodbrook Ln Marietta, GA 30068`
10. `4104 Flat Trl- Ricardo Reeder`
11. `6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141`

Ideal Output Example:

Before:
`6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141`

After:
`6621 Lake Valley Dr`

How can I accomplish this using Snowflake SQL? I'm assuming regex_replace is in order? Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What are your logic rules for defining what part of the string is the address and what isn’t?

Comment: I will just point out we have a whole team do this in full code for years. To handle our navigation addresses, unless you have a very contrained problem space or known N valid formats you will not solve this in Snowflake regexp. It is too limited in it patterns.  I’d even suggest the javascript is too limit due to code size limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for all the examples in the list:

```sql
with data as (
    select value --regexp_substr(replace(value, '-', ','), '([0-9]+ [A-Z].*)', 1) value
    from table(split_to_table(
$$143 Evergreen Forest Court
326 Hambrick Park Fayetteville, GA 30215
RE: Owner's Policy - 112 Shagbark Ln Mooresville, NC 28115
RE: Owner's Policy - 540 Clearbrook Dr Covington, GA 30016
Closed 9/1/21 4421 Home Stakes Dr Parkton, NC 28371
RP 9/16- 352 Hampton St Elloree, SC 29047
RP: 9/15- 124 Lake Grove Rd Simpsonville, SC 29681
FHA 3/2/22- 6083 Holiday Blvd Forest Park, GA 30297
RD 10/1/21 Roxanne Sellers- 311 Woodbrook Ln Marietta, GA 30068
4104 Flat Trl- Ricardo Reeder$$, '\n')
))

select regexp_substr(value, '[0-9]+ [^0-9]* (Court|Park|Ln|Dr|St|Rd|Trl)')
from data
;
```

This solution is based on having a limited set of possible road types at the end.

[image]

As Simeon says in the comments I expect this to get more complex the more examples you find. At certain time you'll have to move from finding examples and asking for more complex regexes to defining rules on your end.

Comment: Forgot to add the last example that this solution doesn't cover `6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141`

Comment: Did you try it? What results did you get?

Comment: Yes it gave me null for the the following examples: `6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141` and  `336 Oak Leaf Pl Acworth, GA 30102` and `2180 Carriage Cir`

Comment: @cyahahn This is the point, you have failed to understand "you have not provided ALL Data, so it's impossible to make a REGUGLAR EXPRESSION (that means a pattern that covers all cases) that covers all cases." Next you will be asking how to parse HTML with a regexp.